# How do I load a page in javascript from its source string?

Tags: javascript

if I have a javascript variable:

```
var page = "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\"><html><head></head><body>Example</body></html>"
```

and I want to load that page, what do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By load, I assume you mean write the contents of page to the current document. If so,

```
document.write(page);
```

See http://javascript.about.com/library/blwrite.htm for some caveats to using this function.

Comment: I accepted this, though it's not working perfectly. In Firefox it is just hanging indefinitely trying to load the page, but if I stop it and refresh then it loads properly.