# How do i replicate HTML Document by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to create HTML Document from html string by javascript.

I simply can create HTML Document from javascript by variable `document`.
I've tried to create HTML Document from html string by this way:

```
var parser=new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(htmlstring, "text/html");
```

It looks good, i have HTML Document from `htmlstring`.
However after using, i see many differences here, for example is `document.location.hostname` , i can't get this from HTML Document from `htmlstring` , i don't know how many properties has been lost.

So is there anyway to replicate exactly `document` from a html string?

Comment: A HTML string doesn't have a location, whereas a document does.

Comment: What do you suppose the location would be for a random string you just parsed, I'm dying to know ?

Comment: @adeneo `document.location.hostname` = domain.

Comment: And what's the domain for your random HTML string, and how is javascript supposed to know `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a page in javascript from its source string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955265/how-do-i-load-a-page-in-javascript-from-its-source-string)

Comment: A seven year old answer saying *"use `document.write`"* is not a very good dupe for this *(or anything)*?

Comment: @adeneo `document.write` will rewrite all the page. i need to assign it to an variable!

Comment: You're already doing that, but a parsed string has no location, it's not a page you're visiting that has an URL.

Comment: @adeneo I don't use `document.write`, all i want is add `document.location` object into HTML Document. The right question is overriding or replicating the `document.location`

Comment: If you read the comments from the top down, you'll see that someone is suggesting this is a duplicate. If you click the link, you can see that duplicate. I'm pointing out that it's not a very good duplicate. I never said you were using, or should be using `document.write`, you shouldn't. If you want to add a property, just do `htmlDoc.location = "Im not getting this"`, but there's no point in doing so, as the string has no location, however hard that seems to be to grok.

Comment: Is requirement to retrieve `document.location.hostname` before `html` `document` is loaded in browser, or after `document` is loaded in browser?

Comment: @TomSawyer Your document has no [browsing context](http://w3c.github.io/html/browsers.html). How this will affect you, highly depends on what you intend to do with the document. Scrape its content? Open it in a frame? Execute its event handlers in some kind of sandbox? Please edit your post; supply some background details.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Blob` from string, `URL.createObjectURL()` on `Blob`, `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\/\/(.*)(?=\/)/`, `Array.prototype.pop()` to retrieve hostname from [`Blob URL`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#blob-url)

```
var htmlstr = "<!doctype html><html><body>abc</body></html>";
var blob = new Blob([htmlstr], {type:"text/html"});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var hostname = url.match(/\/\/(.*)(?=\/)/).pop();
console.log(hostname);
```

Comment: @TomSawyer You could alternatively use `url.split(/^.*\/\/|\/.*|\s/)[1]` to match `hostname`

Comment: Thank, i never heard of that. Does Blob has enough attributes like DOM? like `createElement` , `getelementsbytagname`?

Comment: @TomSawyer _"Does Blob has enough attributes like DOM?"_ Not certain what you mean? `Blob` stores data; see [`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) . What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TomSawyer If you try `console.log(url)` a `Blob URL` should be logged. You can type the `Blob URL` into address bar at browser and navigate to `html` `document` at `htmlstr`, where `DOM` properties should be available.